# OCI8 PHP Error OCIEnvNlsCreate() failed

Tags: php, oracle10g, oci8

I am receiving random errors every so often when connecting/running Oracle SQL Commands. This works 99% of the day, but randomly for around 10 minutes we will get a load of the errors, and the SQL Queries all fail.

**Sorry for all the below code, just trying to assist**

Error is:

```
PHP Warning:  oci_connect() [<a href='function.oci-connect'>function.oci-connect</a>]:  OCIEnvNlsCreate() failed. There is something wrong with your system - please check that LD_LIBRARY_PATH includes the directory with Oracle Instant Client libraries in /var/www/db.php on line 59, referer: https://www.abc.com/abc.php
```

Oracle Instant Client:

```
root@server:/opt/oracle/instantclient# pwd
/opt/oracle/instantclient
root@server:/opt/oracle/instantclient# ls -l
total 99940
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      238 2009-07-03 14:40 BASIC_README
-r--r--r-- 1 root root  1609607 2009-07-03 14:40 classes12.jar
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    67766 2009-07-03 14:40 genezi
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       17 2009-07-03 14:41 libclntsh.so -> libclntsh.so.10.1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 19076649 2009-07-03 14:40 libclntsh.so.10.1
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root root  5656445 2009-07-03 14:40 libnnz10.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       15 2009-07-03 14:41 libocci.so -> libocci.so.10.1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1398244 2009-07-03 14:40 libocci.so.10.1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 72698427 2009-07-03 14:40 libociei.so
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root root   120443 2009-07-03 14:40 libocijdbc10.so
-r--r--r-- 1 root root  1555682 2009-07-03 14:40 ojdbc14.jar
drwxrwxr-x 4 root root     4096 2008-02-17 08:58 sdk
```

Other useful info:

```
root@server:/# cat /etc/apache2/envvars
# envvars - default environment variables for apache2ctl
# Since there is no sane way to get the parsed apache2 config in scripts, some
# settings are defined via environment variables and then used in apache2ctl,
# /etc/init.d/apache2, /etc/logrotate.d/apache2, etc.
export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data
export APACHE_PID_FILE=/var/run/apache2.pid
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/oracle/instantclient
```

Inside the script, We debug any errors, and email a report when these are encountered to try and debug the issue a bit further. I am doing the following:

```
if(isset($ocierr) && $ocierr!="")
   $mb.="Oracle OCI Error: ".$ocierr."\n\n";

$mb.="Oracle Error Message: ".print_r($errmsg,true)."\n\n";
$mb.="Debugging:\nLD_LIBRARY_PATH: ".var_export(getenv('LD_LIBRARY_PATH'),true);
```

which returns:

```
Oracle Error Message: 
Cannot contact to Oracle

Debugging:
LD_LIBRARY_PATH: '/opt/oracle/instantclient'
```

Comment: I suggest you contact the vendor for support, they have got a good support team. Your error looks really esoteric and very specific to the project. And I must admit it smells like that the programmer who left the error message in there was not very sure either why this happens.

Comment: Sorry, who do you mean by "vendor". I believe the error may actually be masking something else, as this happens to every request for say 10 minutes and then works ok. It could be oracle rejecting the connection possibly